# How to use and create attack graphs

Tags: attacks, manual-review, threat-modeling

I am trying to learn more about attack graphs and how they can be used. I have read a little bit about them from some simple Google searches and believe that they could be a useful tool for work. I would like to know how one could go about creating an attach graph, what use cases they are best suited for, and how to prepare a deliverable with the attach graph with recommendations that I can turn into my boss for further review and analysis.

Any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you referring to [Attack Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_tree)? (I guess strictly speaking a tree is a subset of a graph, but semantically they just *feel* different...)

Comment: Besides the wikipedia entry and Bruce Schneier's article, googling also brings a lot of interesting work on the subject.

Comment: @AviD - I am not sure what the differences are between an attack graph and an attack tree.  Any help or understanding of the differences would be appreciated.

Comment: Well I've never heard it called an attack graph, only an attack tree. And, judging from the answers, I'm guessing that's what you meant. As far as data structure go, a tree is a kind of a graph, so...

Comment: Questioner uses "attach graph" twice.  I can't edit that to "attack graph" because I'm not sure if it's correct and because it's less than 6 chars.  But correct spelling helps search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest the Microsoft Press book titled "Threat Modeling"

Comment: I agree - but it's not really much of an answer here... Wanna give some highlights?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not dedicated entirely to thread models, Microsoft's book on the SDL does a fairly in depth talk on the different types of models.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the Microsoft book stuff, you may find interest in "[The Beauty and the Beast: Vulnerabilities in Red Hat's Packages](http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix09/tech/full_papers/neuhaus/neuhaus_html/)" which uses Formal Concept Analysis.